# how to convert date of birth to age and then store it

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

let say I have database table with column of date of birth named `dob`

then, I want to get all the data using :

```
$data = MY_Model::all();
```

How to convert my `$data->dob` to age (years, month, day) and then store it in `$data` so I can access it using `$data->age` ?

Answer (score 3):

Create this method on your model:

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return \Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->dob)->diffInYears(\Carbon::now());
}
```

Now you can call it from the model data directly as `$data->age`

Comment: OP assuming your already using `timestamp` field you can also cast the `dob` to `datetime` and then just do `$this->dob->diffInYears(\Carbon::now());` in the above function. See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateOfBirth = '1994-07-02';
$years = \Carbon::parse($dateOfBirth)->age;
dd($years);
```

for reference [enter link description here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-age-calculate-from-date-using-carbonexample.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the difference broken down between the DOB and now you can return a `CarbonInterval` which will give you access to the years, months, days, etc..

You should be able to cast this field, `dob`, to a 'date' on the Model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'dob' => 'date',
];

public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return $this->dob->diffAsCarbonInterval();
}
```

Then you can access the date difference as the `age` attribute:

```
$record->age; // CarbonInterval
(string) $record->age; // `forHumans` readable format
$record->age->years; // years
$record->age->months; // months
$record->age->days; // days
```